# Primefaces upload file - image not refresh after upload

Tags: file-upload, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have an issue after uploading an image. the image is not refreshed upon upload. The bean is session scoped, and after upload I need to refresh manually the page to see the new image. How can I refresh the graphical Image automatically after image/file upload? thank you

The following code could successfully upload the image but the previous image still visible and the new image could be visible only after refresh:

Platforms: 
jsf 2.2
,tomcat 7.37 
, primefaces 5.0

```
 <h:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p:growl id="growl_1" showDetail="true"/>    

  <p:panelGrid id="pg_photo" 
               style="margin-bottom:10px; 
               width: 50em" 
               styleClass="panelGridCenter"> 
            <f:facet name="header">
                <p:row>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:graphicImage 
                            id="gi_etud" 
                            width="150" 
                            height="120" 
                            value="#{etudiantProfilView.imageEtudAsStream}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:fileUpload id="fu_photo" 
                                      value="#{etudiantProfilView.imageEtudUF}" 
                                      mode="advanced"
                                      dragDropSupport="true"
                                      fileLimit="10"
                                      sizeLimit="100000"
                                      allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|PNG|GIF|JPG|JPEG)$/"
                                      auto="true"
                                      update="growl_1 gi_etud"
                                      fileUploadListener="#{etudiantProfilView.imageUploadListener}"
                                      >
                        </p:fileUpload>
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
            </f:facet>
        </p:panelGrid>
 </h:form>
```

The session bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class EtudiantProfilView implements Serializable {
//some stuff
 public void imageUploadListener(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException {
//save  the image to the hard disk
}
//some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the refresh issue by adding "reload" action to "oncomplete" attribute for uploadFile component:

```
  <p:fileUpload id="fu_photo" value="#{etudiantProfilView.imageEtudUF}" 
                                      mode="advanced"
                                      dragDropSupport="true"
                                      fileLimit="10"
                                      sizeLimit="200000"
                                      allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|PNG|GIF|JPG|JPEG)$/"
                                      auto="true"
                                      update="@form"
                                      oncomplete="window.location.reload();"
                                      fileUploadListener="#{etudiantProfilView.imageUploadListener}"
                                      >
                        </p:fileUpload>
```